# How to set a gemset as default in RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm using RVM in my OS X machine, I use ruby 1.9.2 by default with RVM.

Each time I create a terminal session I have to type "rvm gemset use rails_app", to use my gemset …  I would like "rails_app" to somehow be my default gemset

I've tried doing:

```
 rvm use 1.9.2@rails_app --default
```

but then if I open a new terminal window and type rails I get :

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.0.21, bundler-1.0.21, rake-0.9.2] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1202:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

( it works fine If I just type `rvm gemset use rails_app`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has recently been fixed. Run

```
rvm get head
```

and you should be able to set a default gemset and have it persist across Terminal sessions.

More info is here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/710

Comment: Yeah, I also reported in github. It's the correct answer though :)